# How to set the tintColor of UISegmentControl so the result looks like a specific color?

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

I like to set the selected segment of UISegmentControl exactly to the color of my buttons' background.

So I did this:

```
UIColor *selectedC = [_myBtn backgroundColor];
```

to then set the tint color like this

```
 [[[mySC subviews] objectAtIndex:1] setTintColor:selectedC];
```

However the result looks different (of course), since this is the tint color and not the resulting color.

Interestingly setting segment 0 or segment 1 with selectedC results in the same color (which is good).

All I need to know is how to either 
- set the color of the segment control so the result has in fact the color of my button or 
- find out the correct tint color that has to be used so the segment with the tint color looks like my button

I hope there is some kind of "backward" logic to find out the tint color for a specific output color.

Comment: What colour is your button? Maybe are you using an image for background color or pattern image then ofcourse getting backgroundColor will return different color than what you expect or maybe even nil.

Comment: the color is just a background color chosen in the pallete

Comment: I am assuming your segmented control is created programatically? If its using interface builder then you could set the tint under Attribute inspector -> Tint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..in fact the error was NOT with the code signing but with the fact that the scheme had 2 targets instead of one.

I did not even know that this is possible. Having corrected the scheme to only contain the C target everything was OK.